# Apex Sharing trigger

Tags: apex, sharing-rule

I have been trying to create a trigger that acts in the following:
Whenever scrum team is created,
look up via account, gather the account id, query salesforce to get all contact id's related to account id, share team record with all contacts.
I have have all the logic to pull the contacts related to the account but am struggling with the sharing rule.

Here's what I have so far.

```
trigger ScrumTeamSharing on agf__ADM_Scrum_Team__c(after insert) {
if (trigger.isInsert) {
List <agf__ADM_Scrum_Team__Share> rShare = new List <agf__ADM_Scrum_Team__Share>();
    agf__ADM_Scrum_Team__Share TeamShare;

    for(agf__ADM_Scrum_Team__c ADM : Trigger.new){
        TeamShare = new agf__ADM_Scrum_Team__Share();
        // Set ID of record being shared
        TeamShare.ParentId = ADM.Id;

        // Set ID of user or group being granted access
        //TeamShare.UserOrGroupId = ADM.@@INSERT ID HERE

        // Set Access Level
        TeamShare.AccessLevel = 'Read';

        //Set sharing reason for team
        //TeamShare.RowCause = 
    String IdTeam = ADM.Id;
    String assAcc = ADM.Account_ID__c;
    List<Account> alist = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id=:assAcc];

    System.debug('a' + alist);

    List<Contact> clist = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Contact.AccountId IN :alist];

    System.debug('c' + clist);
    /*while(clist.size() > 0) {
        int i = clist.size();
        clist[i].add();//add to the team reports
        i--;
    }*/
```

I am relatively new to apex so any feedback would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do manual sharing using Apex. It is possible to manually share a record to a user or a group using Apex or the SOAP API. If the owner of the record changes, the sharing is automatically deleted.

To access sharing programmatically, you must use the share object associated with the standard or custom object for which you want to share. For example, AccountShare is the sharing object for the Account object, ContactShare is the sharing object for the Contact object, and so on. In addition, all custom object sharing objects are named as follows, where MyCustomObject is the name of the custom object:

```
MyCustomObject__Share

// Create new sharing object for the custom object Job.
   ContactShare jobShr  = new ContactShare();


  // Set the ID of record being shared.
  jobShr.ParentId = recordId;

  // Set the ID of user or group being granted access.
  jobShr.UserOrGroupId = userOrGroupId;

  // Set the access level.
  jobShr.AccessLevel = 'Read';

  // Set rowCause to 'manual' for manual sharing.
  // This line can be omitted as 'manual' is the default value for sharing objects.
  //jobShr.RowCause = Schema.Job__Share.RowCause.Manual;

  // Insert the sharing record and capture the save result. 
  // The false parameter allows for partial processing if multiple records passed 
  // into the operation.
  Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(jobShr,false);
```

More details you can check [here: Apex manual Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)